# Icons for my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, project-settings

I saw in apple developer documents that i need to putty icons in the main bundle and than set the CFBundleIcons so it has the name of the file.

But i'm looking in my info.plist and i don't see any CFBundleIcons any where… How do i make it appear? I tried creating a new line and write it but it didn't help.

Thanks…

Comment: Is there anything like Icon, Icon file

Comment: In the plist file there is nothing that has to do with the word Icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the info.plist there should be a key like: **Icon file** check the below screen shot:

[image: Icon]

If there is no key like that add a key and value yourself.

When you need to add different icon files for retina display add the key of info.plist like:

[image: Different icons]

Comment: But I understand there is more than one icon to add. They ask for all kinds of different sizes, for iPhone, iPad, appstore and so on. Where  do i put all of these?

Comment: @user1461635: you need to add differnt icons for retina display in info.plist. The appstore icon is added on iTunes connect when you submit your application.

Comment: @user1461635: With pleasure :)